# How can I download and set the filenames using wget -i?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wget

I wanted to know how to define the input file for wget, in order to download several files and set a custom name for them, using `wget -i filename`

Analog example using -O

```
wget -O customname url
```

Answer (score 9):

`-O filename` works only when you give it a single URL.
With multiple URLs, all downloaded content ends up in `filename`.

You can use a `while...loop`:

```
cat urls.txt | while read url
do
    wget "$url" -O "${url##*/}"  # <-- use custom name here
done
```

Comment: What's the difference between default output filename and this filename? Both will be ugly and non-readable.

Comment: How would it be possible to set a custom name for each url defined inside urls.txt

For example, in urls.txt i define `url name[new line]url name`